# Landing page for SSRS server or error html page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have an SSRS server to provide reports in our organization of tens of thousands of users. Users are granted access to folders on the server by AD groups. A common scenario is that users will request access to the reports and it takes a long time for the helpdesk to figure out what they are talking about and route the request back to our group.

What I need is to cause the SSRS server to display a page with instructions for how to request access when a user is denied. How do I do this?

I have googled many times and found nothing but very complicated discussion about branding and what not. All I need is to have a custom error page displayed. Can I do that on top through IIS or something? How do people make a "public" home page for their SSRS server so that users who stumble upon it via email chains and word of mouth can be directed to the folks who manage the server so we can help them?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e8ca8a9f-9353-4099-9179-97fd3b39ed50/ssrs-custom-error-messages

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in?

Answer (score 0):

I start by giving domain users access to the report server home page.

Then I create new roles in SQL Server Management studio, SSMS. After opening up SSMS, click on "Connect" and select "Reporting Services…"

[image: login]

Enter your Server Name and login information and then click Connect.

[image: connect]

After connecting to the Report Server, open the Security Folder right click on "Roles" and click on "New Role…"

I created 2 new roles ("Browser Group", "Functional Owner") with the same permission as "Browser".

- `Functional Owner` - who approves access to the report folder
- `Browser Group` - who has access to the reports by folder

Then on the report manager click on the down arrow for a folder and select "Security"

Then click "New Role Assignment"

Then enter the Active Directory group or an email address and check the new role you created.

You can then query the server for the permissions and show these in a report (use a service account to run the report). I deploy the report to the root directory on the report server and name it `.How to get access to a report folder`. I include the "." at the front of the report name to sort to the top.

#### Report SQL

```
;WITH 
nonreport_folders
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Images')
    , ( 'SharedDataSets')
    , ( 'Data Sources')
    , ( '')
    ) tbl ([FolderName]) 
)
, 
user_list
AS
(
    SELECT 
          usr.[UserID]
        , usr.[UserName]
        , [UserNameFormat] = 
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('\', usr.[UserName]) > 0 THEN UPPER(SUBSTRING(usr.[UserName] ,CHARINDEX('\', usr.[UserName]) + 1, LEN(usr.[UserName])))
                ELSE usr.[UserName] 
            END 
    FROM 
        dbo.[Users] AS usr
)
, 
reporting_roles
AS
(
    SELECT 
          cat.[Name]
        , rol.[RoleName]
        , usr.[UserNameFormat]
    FROM 
        dbo.[Catalog] AS cat
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[PolicyUserRole] AS urol ON urol.[PolicyID] = cat.[PolicyID]
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[Roles] AS rol ON urol.[RoleID] = rol.[RoleID]
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[Policies] AS pol ON urol.[PolicyID] = pol.[PolicyID]
        LEFT JOIN user_list AS usr ON urol.[UserID] = usr.[UserID]
        LEFT JOIN nonreport_folders AS nrf ON nrf.[FolderName] = cat.[Name]
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND cat.[Type] = 1
        AND nrf.[FolderName] IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
          [FolderName] = rpt.[Name]
        , [UserNameFormat] = STUFF((SELECT '; ' + rol.UserNameFormat FROM reporting_roles rol WHERE rol.[RoleName] = rpt.[RoleName] AND rol.[Name] = rpt.[Name] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
        , [RoleName]
    FROM 
        reporting_roles AS rpt
) as s
PIVOT
(
    MAX([UserNameFormat])
    FOR [RoleName] IN ([Browser Group], [Functional Owner])
)AS pvt ORDER BY 1
```

In the report, you can also create a hyperlink to create an email for requesting access to each folder. You can include a message for the help desk for which Active Directory group the user needs based on the "Browser Group" role and cc the "Functional Owner" for approval. I'd also use a parameter for the help desk email.

#### Report Example

[image: report]

- [Icon reference page](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/silk-icons-by-famfamfam.html)

#### Report XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
  <Description>A list of report folders with permission groups and function owners</Description>
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <Author>Anthony Duguid</Author>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="ReportServer">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>Data Source=YourServerName;Initial Catalog=ReportServer</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:SecurityType>Integrated</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>2ff706bc-1b72-4676-bb2a-10cc2737189c</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="FolderPermissions">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>ReportServer</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>;WITH 
nonreport_folders
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Images')
    , ( 'SharedDataSets')
    , ( 'Data Sources')
    , ( '')
    ) tbl ([FolderName]) 
)
, 
user_list
AS
(
    SELECT 
          usr.[UserID]
        , usr.[UserName]
        , [UserNameFormat] = 
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('\', usr.[UserName]) &gt; 0 THEN UPPER(SUBSTRING(usr.[UserName] ,CHARINDEX('\', usr.[UserName]) + 1, LEN(usr.[UserName])))
                ELSE usr.[UserName] 
            END 
    FROM 
        dbo.[Users] AS usr
)
, 
reporting_roles
AS
(
    SELECT 
          cat.[Name]
        , rol.[RoleName]
        , usr.[UserNameFormat]
    FROM 
        dbo.[Catalog] AS cat
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[PolicyUserRole] AS urol ON urol.[PolicyID] = cat.[PolicyID]
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[Roles] AS rol ON urol.[RoleID] = rol.[RoleID]
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[Policies] AS pol ON urol.[PolicyID] = pol.[PolicyID]
        LEFT JOIN user_list AS usr ON urol.[UserID] = usr.[UserID]
        LEFT JOIN nonreport_folders AS nrf ON nrf.[FolderName] = cat.[Name]
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND cat.[Type] = 1
        AND nrf.[FolderName] IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
          [FolderName] = rpt.[Name]
        , [UserNameFormat] = STUFF((SELECT '; ' + rol.UserNameFormat FROM reporting_roles rol WHERE rol.[RoleName] = rpt.[RoleName] AND rol.[Name] = rpt.[Name] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
        , [RoleName]
    FROM 
        reporting_roles AS rpt
) as s
PIVOT
(
    MAX([UserNameFormat])
    FOR [RoleName] IN ([Browser Group], [Functional Owner])
)AS pvt ORDER BY 1</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="FolderName">
          <DataField>FolderName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Browser_Group">
          <DataField>Browser Group</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Functional_Owner">
          <DataField>Functional Owner</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>0.6cm</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>5.5cm</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>7.39208cm</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>6.49521cm</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.6cm</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox24">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value />
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Arial</FontFamily>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox23</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox25">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Folder Name</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox22</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="RoleName2">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Group</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>RoleName</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox12">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Owner</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox12</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.6cm</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Image Name="image10">
                          <Source>Embedded</Source>
                          <Value>email</Value>
                          <Sizing>Clip</Sizing>
                          <ActionInfo>
                            <Actions>
                              <Action>
                                <Hyperlink>="mailto:" &amp; Parameters!HelpDeskEmail.Value &amp; "?subject=Access to report folder: " &amp; Fields!FolderName.Value &amp; "&amp;cc=" &amp; Fields!Functional_Owner.Value &amp; "&amp;body=I would like access to the report folder. Please add me to the following Active Directory group: " &amp; Fields!Browser_Group.Value</Hyperlink>
                              </Action>
                            </Actions>
                          </ActionInfo>
                          <ToolTip>request access to report folder</ToolTip>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                              <Width>0.5pt</Width>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>1.5pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingTop>1.5pt</PaddingTop>
                          </Style>
                        </Image>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="FolderName2">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!FolderName.Value</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>FolderName</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="txtRoleName2">
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!Browser_Group.Value</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Functional_Owner">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!Functional_Owner.Value</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Functional_Owner</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
            <TablixColumnHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixColumnHierarchy>
            <TablixRowHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                </TablixMember>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="Details" />
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixRowHierarchy>
            <DataSetName>FolderPermissions</DataSetName>
            <Height>1.2cm</Height>
            <Width>19.98729cm</Width>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
            </Style>
          </Tablix>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>0.47244in</Height>
        <Style />
      </Body>
      <Width>7.86901in</Width>
      <Page>
        <PageHeight>29.7cm</PageHeight>
        <PageWidth>21cm</PageWidth>
        <LeftMargin>2cm</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>2cm</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>2cm</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>2cm</BottomMargin>
        <ColumnSpacing>0.13cm</ColumnSpacing>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="HelpDeskEmail">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>yourhelpdesk@yourcompany.com</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>HelpDeskEmail</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="FunctionalOwner">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>Functional Owner</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>FunctionalOwner</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
      <MultiValue>true</MultiValue>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="BrowserGroup">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>Browser Group</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>BrowserGroup</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
      <MultiValue>true</MultiValue>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>1</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>3</NumberOfRows>
      <CellDefinitions>
        <CellDefinition>
          <ColumnIndex>0</ColumnIndex>
          <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
          <ParameterName>HelpDeskEmail</ParameterName>
        </CellDefinition>
        <CellDefinition>
          <ColumnIndex>0</ColumnIndex>
          <RowIndex>1</RowIndex>
          <ParameterName>FunctionalOwner</ParameterName>
        </CellDefinition>
        <CellDefinition>
          <ColumnIndex>0</ColumnIndex>
          <RowIndex>2</RowIndex>
          <ParameterName>BrowserGroup</ParameterName>
        </CellDefinition>
      </CellDefinitions>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <EmbeddedImages>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="email">
      <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>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</ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
  </EmbeddedImages>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>73bf78ec-5d72-4bb2-bdf4-804444e517c6</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

#### Expression Example

```
="mailto:" & Parameters!HelpDeskEmail.Value & "?subject=Access to report folder: " & Fields!FolderName.Value & 
"&cc=" & Fields!Functional_Owner.Value & 
"&body=I would like access to the report folder. Please add me to the following Active Directory group: " & Fields!Browser_Group.Value
```

[image: image properties]

#### Email Example

[image: email]

---

[Here are some SSRS examples I use to query the report server.](https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples/blob/master/README.md)